# VirtualBox Bridged Networking is not working (NAT and Host-Only works)

Tags: debian, networking, virtualbox

I'll try to be brief and include all the things I've tried out so far:

- Guest OS: Debian Wheezy
- Host OS: Windows 7
- Setting networking to *NAT* works.
- Setting networking to *host-only* works as well.
- Setting networking to *bridged* (the one I need) does **not** work.
- VBox Additions are up-to-date (first removed the Debian packages and reinstalled the ones provided by VirtualBox).
- `ifconfig` shows the device
- Setting an IP-Address manually with `ifconfig eth0 <unused-ip>` and then pinging a server in the network range does not work (`Destination Host Unreachable`)
- I also set up a default route, but as it's on the same network (a simple `/24` net), that should not (and does not) make a difference.
- The Host has two NICs. I completely disabled the one which is unused. Just to make sure that VirtualBox is not being confused.
- Running `dhclient eth0` does not work.

Looking into `/var/log/messages` I can see the network device reacting when I disconnect/reconnect it via the VirtualBox interface:

```
Mar  1 11:27:23 sleeperian kernel: [ 1895.172149] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Down
Mar  1 11:27:33 sleeperian kernel: [ 1905.193469] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
```

---

What I find most curious, is the error from ping (`Destination Host Unreachable`). The IP-Address and Netmask are correct (pinging `192.168.1.1` btw):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:25:a9:32  
          inet addr:192.168.1.13  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe25:a932/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:30241 (29.5 KiB)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: your eth0 has to has default gw.

Comment: I set up a default route (bullet point #9). Also, this is only necessary if you are accessing (f.ex. pinging) an address *outside* of your network. This would be the case for internet access. But I was pinging one of the network hosts, so the default route should not be necessary. Nevertheless, I set one up without any luck.

Comment: What kind of NIC is on the host? A bridged virtual network works by putting the NIC on the host into promiscuous mode, which doesn't always work with WiFi NICs.

Comment: It's a desktop machine with an on-board NIC. I am not on that machine, but it is a `Marvell Yukon` something something :) And I think I already had bridged networking working at some point. Not sure though if it was on the same machine. I will double check the "promiscuous" mode setting though. VBox has a setting for that where you can allow/forbid it. But I think that setting is okay. Could it have something to do with UAC?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The problem was promiscuous mode! The default setting was "Deny" in virtual box, and I did not touch the default. Changing it to "Allow VMs" made it work. If you will formulate your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Oh! My suggestion actually assumed you were using promiscuous mode. I wonder why they even allow bridged networking to be configured without promiscuous mode. I'll look into it. But really, you found the solution yourself, not me, so feel free to write an answer.

Comment: Well not really. My network knowledge is limited. And I don't know what "promiscuous" mode means. I only know some apps (like wireshark) need it, and that you usually need SU privs to activate it. That's about it. I thought the "Deny" on prom. mode was the default and did not touch it. Without you telling me about it, I would not have found out... maybe after aimlessly clicking around. But I don't usually do that. I usually only touch settings I understand ;)